# Unable to push to Heroku due to 'Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, babeljs

I have tried just about everything to try push my app to heroku. This is the latest error.

```
remote:        Compiling...
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        Hash: f8c9f7bfa5b264fe0b58
remote:        Version: webpack 4.46.0
remote:        Time: 727ms
remote:        Built at: 07/07/2022 3:14:08 AM
remote:         2 assets
remote:        Entrypoint application = js/application-322f69d6aee6dcb0030d.js js/application-322f69d6aee6dcb0030d.js.map
remote:        [0] ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 4.08 KiB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
remote:        
remote:        ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
remote:        Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
remote:        Error: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'
remote:        Require stack:
remote:        - /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
remote:        - /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
remote:        - /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
remote:        - /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
remote:        - /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
remote:        - /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
remote:        - /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
remote:        - /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
remote:        - /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
remote:        - /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
remote:        - /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/validate-options.js
remote:        - /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js
remote:        - /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
remote:        - /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
remote:            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
remote:            at resolve (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:164:23)
remote:            at resolveStandardizedName (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:111:7)
remote:            at resolvePlugin (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:55:10)
remote:            at loadPlugin (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:63:20)
remote:            at loadPlugin.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at createDescriptor (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:187:16)
remote:            at createDescriptor.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at step (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/gensync/index.js:261:32)
remote:            at evaluateAsync (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/gensync/index.js:291:5)
remote:            at /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/gensync/index.js:44:11
remote:            at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
remote:            at Function.async (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/gensync/index.js:43:15)
remote:            at Function.all (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/gensync/index.js:216:13)
remote:            at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at createDescriptors (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:142:41)
remote:            at createDescriptors.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at createPluginDescriptors (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:138:17)
remote:            at createPluginDescriptors.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at plugins (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:65:26)
remote:            at plugins.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at mergeChainOpts (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:419:34)
remote:            at mergeChainOpts.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:378:14
remote:            at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at loadFileChain (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:232:24)
remote:            at loadFileChain.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at buildRootChain (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:95:27)
remote:            at buildRootChain.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at loadPrivatePartialConfig (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:103:62)
remote:            at loadPrivatePartialConfig.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:149:25
remote:            at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at step (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/gensync/index.js:269:25)
remote:            at evaluateAsync (/tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/gensync/index.js:291:5)
remote:            at /tmp/build_55951252/node_modules/gensync/index.js:93:9
remote:        
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

There is nothing in my /javascript/packs/application.js. I have not found anything that references this file as a necessary step to build the referenced module in the error.

This is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "example-app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.18.6",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.3",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "5.0.0-beta2",
    "node": "^18.4.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "webpack-config": "^7.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/core": "7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.15.0"
  },
  "postinstall": "npm rebuild node-sass"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error means you need to install the package: `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`.

Comment: It’s either a peer dep for another Babel plugin or your build is using it.

Comment: @JBallin I just kept installing packages until I was able to deploy. It eventually worked! Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

The error means you need to install the package: `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`.

It’s either a peer dependency for another Babel plugin, or your build is using it directly (naming can be different in Babel config).